# Is it allowed to add the logo of the corresponding game to tagwiki's?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki

Just as the title says, is it allowed to add the logo of the corresponding game to tagwiki's? For example, I just edited the tagwiki roller-coaster-tycoon-3 and added the logo of the game at it. [image: Tagwiki roller-coaster-tycoon-3]

Comment: The logo is sponsored by the company. They have to pay to get the logo

Comment: @UniKitty I think you are confusing this request with a sponsored tag, where the logo appears directly on the tag itself, which is a separate issue.

Comment: Side note: we have set [standards for tag wikis and excerpts.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7837/28182), so try to stick to those formats when making edits to tag wikis :-)

Comment: It puts the lotion on it's skin...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that is the only edit you are doing to a tag wiki/excerpt, it isn't substantial enough. There isn't any real reason to add these to the wikis, as generally these are just supposed to be a brief bit of text to tell people what the tag is about. Does adding the logo give any sort of extra information that the poster needs to understand the tag? Not really. I would then suggest avoiding adding them, as they don't add anything to the tag wiki that is really necessary to understand the tag.

Comment: I thought the reason non-substantial edits were discouraged was because they caused noise on the front page. Is this even a problem with tag wikis?