# Is it worth adding a screenshot to tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I have recently added tag wikis for several games, and loosely based the content on this [question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/game-card-like-template-for-tag-wiki).  I have added very basic information to help identify the games in question (full name, publisher, year of first release, platforms etc).

I stumbled on this [question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/is-it-allowed-to-add-the-logo-of-the-corresponding-game-to-tagwikis) regarding logos which made me think that maybe (and particular for more obscure games) it would be worth adding a screenshot of the game to the tag wiki.  Often pictures can do a lot more than descriptions, and in this case I believe just seeing a single screenshot will help jog your memory about older games.

If I come across a tag with no wiki can I add a single screenshot with a simple description of the game?

Comment: If you do this, make sure you use the imgur upload button/tool so your image isn't relying on an external link (which may break if the image gets taken down or moved). Also, remember to [fill out the image description field](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7470/28182)

Comment: Yes, was planning on imgur upload but good point on image description.

Comment: Related: [How should I write tag wikis?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7837/52800)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this point in time, it's sad to say, it's a waste of time and potential fair use trouble. Tag wiki pages are very low traffic pages. Just link to the relevant Wikipedia article, if any.

If you want to contribute screenshots to the site, you'd do better to donate them to a needy answer or question.